# Is it possible to optimize large switch on strings?

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm looking through a friend of mine's library because he asked about optimization and I came across a section of code like this:

```
long digit = 0;

switch (word) {
    case "zero":
        digit = 0;
        break;
    case "a":
    case "one":
        digit = 1;
        break;
    case "two":
        digit = 2;
        break;
    case "three":
        digit = 3;
        break;
    case "four":
        digit = 4;
        break;
    case "five":
        digit = 5;
        break;
    case "six":
        digit = 6;
        break;
    case "seven":
        digit = 7;
        break;
    case "eight":
        digit = 8;
        break;
    case "nine":
        digit = 9;
        break;
    case "ten":
        digit = 10;
        break;
    case "eleven":
        digit = 11;
        break;
    case "twelve":
        digit = 12;
        break;
    case "thirteen":
        digit = 13;
        break;
    case "fourteen":
        digit = 14;
        break;
    case "fifteen":
        digit = 15;
        break;
    case "sixteen":
        digit = 16;
        break;
    case "seventeen":
        digit = 17;
        break;
    case "eighteen":
        digit = 18;
        break;
    case "nineteen":
        digit = 19;
        break;
    case "twenty":
        digit = 20;
        break;
    case "thirty":
        digit = 30;
        break;
    case "fourty":
        digit = 40;
        break;
    case "fifty":
        digit = 50;
        break;
    case "sixty":
        digit = 60;
        break;
    case "seventy":
        digit = 70;
        break;
    case "eighty":
        digit = 80;
        break;
    case "ninety":
        digit = 90;
        break;
}

return digit;
```

I've seen a few questions on here about [exactly how a switch might work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905/c-switch-statement-limitations-why#48259), but they conveniently don't mention cases with strings. Can a switch statement like the one above be optimized in any way?

Comment: optimized ? Does it have a measured performance problem?

Comment: I'm willing to bet a dollar that somewhere in this program there is a bug whereby the string "twenty-a" is parsed as 21. Also, "forty" is misspelled.

Comment: Mitch Wheat - No, but in my book you don't optimize bad code into good code, you optimize good code into better code.

Comment: Mitch Wheat - It works? Do you know a better way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you make this switch statement as fast as possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837546/how-would-you-make-this-switch-statement-as-fast-as-possible)

Comment: @Corey: In my book, you don't waste shareholder money by spending time and money "optimizing" code that is (1) already good enough, and (2) probably not the slowest thing in the program. Spend your time getting the code *correct* before you spend time getting it fast. I've found two bugs already just by glancing at it; spend your time getting the bugs out.

Comment: @Eric There are no shareholders, this is a personal project. "twenty-a" does not get converted to 21, other checks elsewhere prevent this, and the spelling check (albeit I'm glad you found it) is a fix outside of the focus of the question. We already have unit tests set up and are iteratively switching between debugging, optimizing and then debugging those optimizations.

Comment: Well then, I owe you a dollar! :-)

Comment: @Corey Ogburn: There are always shareholders, just maybe not what you traditionally think of as shareholders. Perhaps "stakeholders" is a more appropriate term, but the point remains that someone somewhere (it might only be you) has an interest or concern in this project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Oded said, you can put them in a `Dictionary`. But in fact, the .NET compiler already does this for you: it builds a jump table (via a `Dictionary<string, SomeDelegate>`) that allows to switch on the value in O(1).

*That said*, I actually find using a `Dictionary<string, int>` *more readable* than a `switch` here.

Comment: It does? Cool, didn't know that, could you link to a source?

Comment: That's an interesting bit of knowledge. Can you provide a link with more info?

Comment: I did not know that as well, I'd be curious to read more about that.

Comment: @mafutrct I don’t have a source handy but you can just see for yourself by using Reflector or a disassembled .NET executable.

Comment: @James - one more for your "Little Wonders"?

Comment: @Konrad: I do agree on the readability comment.  If it's just looking up a value and returning the result, the Dictionary directly will have far less vertical bloat size than a switch (especially since you can use a collection initializer).

Comment: Also, using a dictionary provides further conveniences like reverse lookups, ie: ContainsValue().

Answer (score 9):

You can put these in a `Dictionary<string,int>` and return the `int` for the string key.

```
var wordsToNumbers = new Dictionary<string,int>();
wordsToNumbers.Add("one", 1);
...
wordsToNumbers.Add("ninety", 90);


// elsewhere
return wordsToNumbers[word];
```

Note:

As others have noted in the comments - the idea is to build the dictionary *once* and reuse it. One way would be to use a field and populate it in a constructor, then use it in other methods.

Comment: beat me to it! Just make sure the process is cached some how. This way it's not building the Dictionary more than once.

Comment: Just a note: this can only be a good idea if you keep the dictionary around and reuse it every time you call this weird month-digit function. It would be *not* be a good idea to build a dictionary every time and search it.

Comment: I seem to remember the compiler will use a Dictionary too when that's profitable.

Comment: @Henk - This is what Konrad is also saying. Do you have a link to documentation to that effect?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a better optimization might be to have a static Dictionary:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, long> _lookup = new Dictionary<string, long>
   {
       { "one", 1 },
       { "two", 2 },
       { "three", 3 },
       // etc...
   }
```

Then just access to use:

```
var number = "one";
var result = _lookup[number];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary instead of a massive switch.  As far as timings, time the switch versus the dictionary.  The dictionary would be cleaner I think, but may perform the same.

Comment: I didn't get the load new answers warning dialog, so this answer is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Measure if it is required. Use a profiler.
2. The easiest way is a Dictionary. It would be very fitting for your use case, too.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on string will switch to using a hashtable when the number of strings gets to be large enough that a hashtable is quicker than a series of comparisons.

You can verify this using Reflector.