# Is there a more efficient alternative to the switch statement for variables that rarely change in gameloops

Tags: c#, xna

Lets say you had something that was going to stay changed for a while, like the game state of of a game. In this game, the game loop runs constantly,  and it's update method runs constantly.

You can accomplish a game state by using a switch statement with a variable that represents the game state, and depending on it's value, it will execute code for the menu or gameplay or another state of the game.

Every game update, it will go through this switch statement first, and this seems inefficient

Is there a more efficient alternative to the switch statement for stuff that is not going to change for a while? I can see this being done with a variable for a method, but c# does not support method variables I think.

Comment: If it's a switch statement it is not really inefficient. A long chain of expressions, maybe, but just a switch on a single variable? Don't fix performance "problems" before you have determined that they exist.

Comment: Of course I know this is not going to kill the game but I am new to c# and I just want to learn in case I need something like this in the future, and this particularly bothers me

Comment: I have an answer for you, but well, as Robert said, go and accept some answers first. And C# does support method variables. It's called delegate in the .NET world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard approach to change switch into something is to use Dictionary of choice-to-handler. This is discussed here [Refactor my C# code - Switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561401/refactor-my-c-sharp-code-switch-statement)

```
var choices = new Dictionary<ChoiceType, Func<ChoiceResult> > (); 
...

public ChoiceResult HereWasSwitch(ChoiceType myChoice)
{
  return choices[myChoice]();
}
```

Another approach is to use ploymorphism and replace each choice with class handling it. Check out http://hanuska.blogspot.com/2006/08/swich-statement-code-smell-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Create more than one loop depending on what part the user is located at.

Chances are you will never use up the entire cpu time, so look at writing a microtime function of some sort that will check input every 1/60th of a second. The same can be applied to video rendering, most monitors update every 60th, or 120th of a second. You don't need to use 100% of cpu, or gpu to render your scenes in your game.

If your writing your game using windows api you dont really have to bother, as windows will automatically handle how often input, and updates are applied to your form data.